# Including a  section with "dynamic prototypes" in a static Tableview with "static cells"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to define a static tableview with one dynamic section
Is that possible?

section 0 shall be static, the lables are wired in xcode with the outlets.

section 1 shall be dynamic

I tried this, but I don´t know what cell I shall return for the static part.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCellBasic";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

switch (indexPath.section)
{ case 0:
    return // I don´t know what

  case 1:
    cell.textLabel =@"dynamic";
    return cell;    
}
```

EDIT 1;
now I tried:

```
case 0: return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but got:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:6072
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Comment: the property:"content" in xcode, whith can be "static cells" or "dynamic prototypes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a partial solution for this problem

In the Table view data source methods I return the superclasses result for the static cells, for the dynamic cells I return the needed dynamic values.

In - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: returns nil so I create a new UITableViewCell

The remaining problem:

in xcode you have to specify, the number of rows in the "dynamic section" (whitch is ofcourse not dynamic). You cann´t display more than the maximum you defined here (or get an exception ;-)).

Samplecode:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
  switch (section) 
  { case STATIC_SECTION:
      return  [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    case DYNAMIC_SECTION
      return NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS; 
  }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCellBasic";
  UITableViewCell *cell; 

  switch (indexPath.section)
  {
    case STATIC_SECTION:
      return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    case DYNAMIC_SECTION:
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (!cell) 
      {  cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
      }

      cell.textLabel.text=DYNAMIC_TEXT;
      return cell;    
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually you can add any number of dynamic cells. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043521/adding-unknown-number-of-rows-to-static-cells-uitableview/10060997#comment15940351_10060997)

Answer (score -1):

instead of a switch try using some good old if statements

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ 
       if(section==STATIC_SECTION){
           return  *the number of rows in the static section*
       }
       else{
           return NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS; 
       }
  }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCellBasic";
    UITableViewCell *yourCell = [tableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexpath:indexPath];

    yourCell.text = *your dynamic text or something*

    return yourCell;
}
```

now assuming your static cells don't have reuse identifiers, cause that would just be redundant,  and since you only need one prototype cell for reuse this should be your setup