# Is it possible to use editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath -> UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert using 'Static Cells" for a UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I think my question is pretty clear.
I have set up a `uitableview` with static cells laid out in the interface builder.
Used stuff like textviews inside the cells, I think it would be a lot of work to change this to a normal tableview where I set my cells programmatically.

So I would like to know if I can still use `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` somehow, I tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible!
Found some help over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060997/871561