# Is there a trick to Insert rows into a TableView w/ Static Cells configured via Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I've got a TableView that I've created in a Storyboard via Static Cells.

The idea is that a section has a single row with a Label and a Switch. When the user taps the Switch "on", the section sprouts some new rows below. Somewhat similar to Wi-Fi settings in the Settings app (which adds new sections, but I'm adding new rows).

[image]

I'm creating this TableView via Storyboard like so:

[image]

And now, the action taken when the switch value changes:

```
- (IBAction)hitSwitch:(id)sender {

    NSArray *indexPathsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0], nil];



    UISwitch *theSwitch = sender;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (theSwitch.on) {

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    } else {

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

I'd expect the normal table view data source methods to be called to display the cells for these new rows, so I've added the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (self.addRowsSwitch.on) {

        return 3;

    } else {

        return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    }

}



- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (!self.addRowsSwitch.on) {

        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    } else {

        UITableViewCell *newCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

        return newCell;

    }

}
```

But according to my handy debugger, tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: is called, returns a value, and then the app crashes before tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

> 2012-08-02 13:16:08.564 TableViewInsertTest[3186:f803] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '***
>   -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x14b2022 0xeb2cd6 0x149e644 0x43bea5 0x2481a8 0x1f3688 0x1f4c2a 0x9743e 0xa50b7 0xa50e5 0x2604 0x14b3e99
>   0x1814e 0x180e6 0xbeade 0xbefa7 0x212c16 0x93b85d 0x1486936 0x14863d7
>   0x13e9790 0x13e8d84 0x13e8c9b 0x139b7d8 0x139b88a 0x15626 0x1ebd
>   0x1e25)

Is there something else I need to do to make this work, or is the type of behaivor that I'm trying to implement not supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding unknown number of rows to 'Static Cells' UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043521/adding-unknown-number-of-rows-to-static-cells-uitableview)