# section value is always 1 in numberOfRowsInSection in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have two sections in tableview that is located inside tableviewcontroller
For some reason the section value in method numberOfRowsInSection is always "1". Thats quite strange because, everything seems fine.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    int i=section;
    if(section==0)
        return 1;
    else{
        return [self.flightDetailsArray count];
    }
}
```

In storyboard i have a table with two sections

Ok, once again doing it for you to understand the problem. Watch this code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    NSLog(@"Section: %d",(int)section);
    if(section==0)
        return 1;
    else{
        return [self.flightDetailsArray count];
    }
}
```

in Log i see "1" always
what's that? its strange

Comment: That is unusual.  Can you show how you know it's never `0`?

Comment: I use debugger. I can even log it. but anyways its always "1"

Comment: I doubt that is the case, so can you please provide more evidence so we can see if you've missed something in your investigation.

Comment: i can provide the storyboard screen, Also note that its a UITableViewController

Comment: I will try to recreate the sections, maybe its some bug with xcode. I tried to clean the project, didnt help.

Comment: what's the use of " int i " ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve. Please just define it then we can try to help you. So far, if you are getting 1 always then may be your array, self.flightDetailsArray has only one object. If so, then in any case, you will get alway 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273531/mixing-static-and-dynamic-uitableviewcontroller-content-causes-nsrangeexception

It seems that it's my issue. i was mixing the satic table with dynamic data.

Comment: What's a "s[t]atic table"?

Comment: table with static cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, guys. The problem was that i used satic type of tableview, but had inside also dynamic cells. So i didn't pay attention to it. Then i changed id to dynamic, and added he dynamic sections and it worked just fine. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the reason behind this due to the fact i'm also a beginner but as far as I'm concerned i think you're trying to return 1 row at first time and in the next step you want to return count of the flightDetailsArray so maybe you can achieve that by these steps :-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    static int i=0
    if(i==0)
        return 1;
        i++;
    else{
        return [self.flightDetailsArray count];
    }


}
```

Comment: i want the first section to contain 1 row, and the second section [self.flightDetailsArray count]
but for some reason section is always "1" 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
I mean the param of this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to return only 1 row in your 1st section and then the number of objects in your `flightDetailsArray`in the second section. If that is the case, then just do this,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section==0)
        return 1;
    else{
        return [self.flightDetailsArray count];
    }
}
```

Now, it may be possible that your second section will also hold 1 row if there is only one object in your `flightDetailsArray`.

Please try to print `NSLog(@"%@", [self.flightDetailsArray count])` and see the object number.