# Adding rows to section in static UITableView crashes the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this piece of code that is taken from several similar questions on SO and I have no idea why it is crashing. I have followed examples from accepted and obviously correct answers.

I have a static table where the first section of the table holds the only static row. The second section is empty at first and is supposed to be populated by an async-task later. First `numOfDynamicRows` is sat to zero, and when the async-task is done, this value is changed to the length of the dict I get back. Everything crashes when I use `reloadData`. I have tried to debug the code and it looks like it is crashing when it comes to the section it is supposed to add new rows.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return numOfDynamicRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int section = indexPath.section;
    int row = indexPath.row;

    if (section == 0) {
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        HomeFeedCell *cell;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            // create a cell
            cell = [[HomeFeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

It is crashing with the follow message (which is confusing me a lot):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
>   empty array'

Comment: As you can read in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043521/adding-unknown-number-of-rows-to-static-cells-uitableview?rq=1 you have to override every tableview delegate method. May be in that issue?

Comment: is ther number of section is Static..?

Comment: Might be easier to tell with the whole class...where are you using the objectAtIndex method, that crash means you're trying to reference an object in an array thats empty