# Adding row to Static UITableView: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to programatically insert a new row between two existing rows in my static `UITableView`, but it crashes saying:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

This is the code I'm using to add the new row

```
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 3) {
    // If this is the first subtask we want it to appear under Sub Tasks
    if (subTaskRow.count == 0) {
         tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        // Added the first subtask
        subTaskRow.addObject(5)
        tableView.reloadData()
    // Other sub tasks should appear below previous sub tasks
    } else {
        let row = (subTaskRow.lastObject as! Int) + 1
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        // Keep track of subsequent subtasks
        subTaskRow.addObject(row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried moving the `subTaskRow.addObject(row)` before the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`!?

Comment: @luk2302 that won't make a difference - subTaskRow is just an array to keep track of the indexPaths of the rows i've added

Comment: i disagree, in your implementation of `numberOfRowsInSection`, what do you return? `subTaskRow.count`maybe!?

Comment: @luk2302 no. it's a static table view. I've not implemented that function at all.

Comment: aaaaah, static tableViews, that is a useful information - take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043521/adding-unknown-number-of-rows-to-static-cells-uitableview you can not *just* insert new rows.

Comment: @luk2302 i'll check it out thanks. I did mention it was static in the title :P

Comment: okay, in the title... :D I was more focused on the body of the question ;)